# Save the default behavior of aliased command

Tags: bash, shell

I have a command in bashrc

```
alias ls="ls -l"
```

Now I want the normal behavior of ls(i.e. only file names)
I am trying

```
alias ls_normal="ls"
```

When I execute ls_normal, it's calling ls, which is ls -l.

So how do I get the default behavior of ls, after I changed it through alias? Is it possible to save it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `\ls`, `'ls'`, `"ls"`, or using the full path to `ls` all prevent alias expansion.

Answer (score 2):

Alias it to a full path:

```
alias ls_normal="/bin/ls"
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to call it with a backslash:

```
alias ls_normal='\ls'
```